# Android studio AVD Hardware Profile Blackberry Q10

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I tried to make a hardware profile for Blackberry Classic 720*720 px resolution and 3.5" device. Then I made an avd with that profile and I got the error

`User Blackberry Classic no longer exists as a device`.

But created profile does exist at the specified path.  What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow your device definition got clobbered.<sup>1</sup> The solution is to recreate the hardware profile. You shouldn't have to delete and re-create the AVD itself, although you will have to restart the AVD Manager after re-creating the device profile. Just make sure to name it exactly what is expected ("Blackberry Classic" in your case).

<sub><sup>1</sup> This happened to me when I created a custom device profile using Android Studio and then later opened up Eclipse with an outdated Android plugin. It decided that since it couldn't parse the hardware profile, it would rename it to `something.bak`. Then it complained that the AVDs that were using that profile were unusable and couldn't be repaired. Very irritating.</sub>